# How to pass multiple arguments to dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, parameters, arguments

```
def mymarks(dict, keys):
    for key in dict:
        print(dict[keys])

marks = {"maths": "85", "chemistry": "70", "english": "76", "biology": '83', "physics": "71"}

mymarks(marks, "chemistry", "biology", "physics")
```

How can I pass multiple arguments to `mymarks()` function? I do not want to print all values of the keys of the marks dictionary. I only want to print the values of sciences subjects keys which are chemistry, biology and physics, so the output would be like:

```
70
83
71
```

I tried to solve it as following, but this resulted in error.

```
def mymarks(dict, keys, keys, keys):
    for key in dict:
        print(dict[keys])

mymarks(marks, keys = "chemistry", keys = "biology", keys = "physics")
```

Comment: Please edit and indet the code properly to make it readable

Comment: Change to `def mymarks(d, *keys)` and `for key in keys: print(d[key])`

Answer (score 0):

```
def mymarks(dict, *keys):
    for key in keys:
        print(dict[key])

marks = {"maths": "85", "chemistry": "70", "english": "76", "biology": '83', "physics": "71"}

mymarks(marks, "chemistry", "biology", "physics")
```

Output :-

> ```
> 70
> 83
> 71
> ```